# Go to 1st link in container unless another link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, containers

Is it possible to go to the 1st link in container when you click anywhere on that container unless another link is clicked in it?

I currently have this:

js:

```
$('.container').click( function() {
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="[link one's link]">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="[link two's link]">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="[link three's link]">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="[link four's link]">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it currently just goes to the 1st link no matter which one I click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.container').click( function(e) {
    window.location = $(e.target).is('a') ? e.target.href : $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FvAgx/)

Comment: This. To supplement, I would change `return false;` to `e.preventDefault();` - just better practice.